# How to get current logged in user using Wordpress Rest Api?

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to add a custom request.

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'custom', '/login', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => function(WP_REST_Request $request) {
            return wp_get_current_user();
        }
    ));
});
```

But it always returns a user with with ID = 0;
I also tried this:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'custom', '/login', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => function(WP_REST_Request $request) {
            return is_user_logged_in();
        }
    ));
});
```

And it always returns false.
But the user is logged in for sure.

I added my custom login

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'custom', '/login', array(
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => function(WP_REST_Request $request) {
            $nonce = wp_create_nonce("wp_rest");
            $user = wp_signon(array('user_login' => $_POST['username'],
                'user_password' => $_POST['password'], "rememberme" => true), false);
            if (is_wp_error($user)) {
                return $user;
            }

            //do_action( 'wp_login', "capad" );
            //$user['isloggedin'] = is_user_logged_in();
            return array('user' => $user,
                'nonce' => $nonce);
        }
    ));
});
```

And I add "X-WP-Nonce" in as a header for http request

And now every request outputs: `{"code":"rest_cookie_invalid_nonce","message":"Cookie nonce is invalid","data":{"status":403}}`

Comment: Did you get this working? Are you able to post the solution? Thanks

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: If you are using third party app or stand alone app then better to use `Application password` for connecting to REST API, because it comes now inbuilt in wordpress from `wordpress 5.6`.

Answer (score 48):

From the [Authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) chapter, in the *REST API Handbook*:

> Cookie authentication is the basic authentication method included with
>   WordPress. When you log in to your dashboard, this sets up the cookies
>   correctly for you, so plugin and theme developers need only to have a
>   logged-in user.
>
> However, the REST API includes a technique called nonces to avoid CSRF
>   issues. This prevents other sites from forcing you to perform actions
>   without explicitly intending to do so. This requires slightly special
>   handling for the API.
>
> For developers using the built-in Javascript API, this is handled
>   automatically for you. This is the recommended way to use the API for
>   plugins and themes. Custom data models can extend wp.api.models.Base
>   to ensure this is sent correctly for any custom requests.
>
> For developers making manual Ajax requests, the nonce will need to be
>   passed with each request. The API uses nonces with the action set to
>   `wp_rest`. These can then be passed to the API via the `_wpnonce` data
>   parameter (either POST data or in the query for GET requests), or via
>   the `X-WP-Nonce` header.

Here's a GET example:

```
https://example.tld/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?_wpnonce=9467a0bf9c
```

or in your case:

```
https://example.tld/wp-json/custom/login/?_wpnonce=9463a0bf9c
```

where the nonce is created from

```
wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' );
```

So most likely you forgot about the **nonce part** when testing your custom  endpoint.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried your solution and I updated my post. Can you please help?

Comment: The nonce must come with the client's request, not be generated in the rest-server's response. Try first, for example, to play with the `/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me/` endpoint where the client sends the nonce and let it display the current user info. @SemyonTikhonenko

Comment: "The API uses nonces with the action set to `wp_rest`" Yep, I always change that, and it screwed me up.

Answer (score 26):

I spent two days searching for a simple way without adding plugins.

first in function.php where you define your api

```
//enqueue the script which will use the api
function api_callings_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('score-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ScoreSaving.js', ['jquery'], NULL, TRUE);
    // Pass nonce to JS.
    wp_localize_script('score-script', 'ScoreSettings', [
      'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('wp_rest'),
    ]);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'api_callings_scripts' );
```

Then your script Ajax call cloud be something like this

```
jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/wp-json/score/update",
      data: {"var1":"value1"},
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-WP-Nonce', ScoreSettings.nonce);
      },
    success: 
        function( data ) {
          console.log( data );
        }
    });
```

Now you can use `get_current_user_id()` inside your API code.

Comment: I think this explains my issues with get_current_user_id. I encountered the problem hile developing a mobile app that uses React-native for the frontend and axios to send requests to the WP REST Api. Instead of a nonce I used a JWT for authentication, because the app code was not directly connected to the WP application. And I see that the plugin that handles the JWT authentication doesn't login the user. It just checks if the token is valid or not.

Comment: Simple, efficient, perfect!

Answer (score 10):

Here is another way

```
$user_id = ""; //<- add this

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'add_custom_users_api');

function add_custom_users_api(){
    $GLOBALS['user_id'] = get_current_user_id(); //<- add this

    // route url: domain.com/wp-json/mmw/v1/testing
    register_rest_route( 'mmw/v1', 'testing', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_custom_users_data',
    ));
}
//Customize the callback to your liking
function get_custom_users_data(){
    return get_user_by( 'id', $GLOBALS['user_id'] ); //<- add this
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**1.** Install  and activate [JWT Authentication for WP REST API plugin](https://pt.wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/), also install  [WP REST API plugin](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API) 
**2.** Now you can run any wordpress default api from mobile app or any other source or by postman. for example hit this url from your app or by postman. https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts 
**3.** By app or by postman, When you will login with valid details (using rest api) you will get back a token. To login and get token, run the following url by postman or by app
https://example.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token

**4.** By this way you will get a token as shown in picture
[image: postman and jwt authentication]

Now use this token to get logged in user details, for example
**5.** make function in function.php

```
function checkloggedinuser()
{
$currentuserid_fromjwt = get_current_user_id();
print_r($currentuserid_fromjwt);
exit;
}

 add_action('rest_api_init', function ()
{
  register_rest_route( 'testone', 'loggedinuser',array(
  'methods' => 'POST',
  'callback' => 'checkloggedinuser'
  ));
});
```

**6.** Now again run this new url in postman or in app to get logged in user details. https://example.com/wp-json/testone/loggedinuser  (replace example.com with your url) [image: use of jwt token]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIqhS.png)
**7.** Also edit your .htaccess file and wp-config.php file according to instructions on pt.wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api

Comment: ... what just happened?

Comment: I have tried with your code and I always get `0`, when I should return the user ID

Comment: @MarioBurga view this link to add code in .htaccess file and wp-config file. https://pt.wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/

Comment: @MarioBurga Let me know if still you are facing any issue with this code.

Comment: This worked out for me in postman.  Authenticated with JWT, used the returned authorization to authenticate other requests.  Thank you!

Comment: Hi from 2020, @MarioBurga did you ever figure out your issue? I am running into the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer use [JWT Authentication for WP REST API](https://pt.wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/), it may be easier to implement with Json Web Tokens.

First you authenticate the client sending a HTTP POST request to the endpoint **/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token** sending **username** and **password** fields to generate a auth token.

A succefull response would be similar to:

```
{
    "token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9qd3QuZGV2IiwiaWF0IjoxNDM4NTcxMDUwLCJuYmYiOjE0Mzg1NzEwNTAsImV4cCI6MTQzOTE3NTg1MCwiZGF0YSI6eyJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjoiMSJ9fX0.YNe6AyWW4B7ZwfFE5wJ0O6qQ8QFcYizimDmBy6hCH_8",
    "user_display_name": "admin",
    "user_email": "admin@localhost.dev",
    "user_nicename": "admin"
}
```

Then you pass the token each request settings the request header **Authorization** like:

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9qd3QuZGV2IiwiaWF0IjoxNDM4NTcxMDUwLCJuYmYiOjE0Mzg1NzEwNTAsImV4cCI6MTQzOTE3NTg1MCwiZGF0YSI6eyJ1c2VyIjp7ImlkIjoiMSJ9fX0.YNe6AyWW4B7ZwfFE5wJ0O6qQ8QFcYizimDmBy6hCH_8
```

Comment: How can I get current user form access token? Is there any method to decode this token and I will get current user id?

Comment: The plugin handles the authorization so wp_get_current_user should return the authenticated user.

Comment: @Gui how can I pass "Authorization" token with postman ? Should I write "Bearer" in key in postman? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @shiv You've to define a header. Create a new header for the request and name it Authorization (this is the key of the header). The value of the header is Bearer token-here

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with the same issue where get_current_user_id() would return 0. After some testing I found this was only the case when sending POST requests.

With GET requests the function returned the logged in user ID, on a POST request it returned 0. This could be due to a server configuration perhaps as this was on a shared hosting environment. I did not find any posts or comments mentioning this before, but this is what happened in my case. A simple workaround could be to pass the user ID back to the frontend in a GET request, store it and send it on POST requests as an extra param.

Comment: you can pass `_wpnonce=<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ); ?>` to your endpoint URL, this seemed to get wp to authenticate the user. Sending the user ID in the client is a bad idea, you could pass it to your callback methods while registering the routes it would be safe.

Comment: ^this worked with post

Answer (score 0):

I think it one of the most flexible way to retrieve the user id in rest callback

```
<?php 

// register route
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'el-dashboard-api', '/generic-comments', [
        'methods'   => 'GET',
        'callback'  => 'get_generic_comments',
        'login_user_id' => get_current_user_id(), // This will be pass to the rest API callback 
    ]);
});


// rest callback
function get_generic_comments($REST_REQUEST_OBJ){

    // get all the passed attrs
    $attrs =  $REST_REQUEST_OBJ->get_attributes();

    // check is login_user_id set as attr
    if( isset($attrs['login_user_id']) && intval($attrs['login_user_id']) > 0  ){

        $user_id        = intval($attrs['login_user_id']);
        $current_user   = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
        
        return "Authorize";

    }
    return "Not authorize";

}
```

Comment: I have added this code in my function.php file it returns the message "Not Authorized".

Comment: Because its a GET request,
To get authorize Access you need to :
1. Login as a user
2. Your AJAX request has to make from same site