# X-WP-Nonce == Cookie nonce is invalid

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, rest, reactjs

On my WordPress REST endpoint, I did a login on wordpress to return a nonce like so:

PHP

```
$authenticated   = wp_authenticate( $userID , $password );
    $isAuthenticated = ( $authenticated instanceof \WP_User ) ? TRUE : FALSE;

    if ( $isAuthenticated )
    {
        $responseData[ "nonce" ] = wp_create_nonce( "rest" );

        return rest_ensure_response( $responseData );
     }
```

Then I returned the nonce through axios back to PHP to verify it and it works!

JS:

```
let axiosSettings = {
        baseURL: "http://site.localhost",
        url: "/wp-json/id3/test/verify",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            n: this.state.nonce
        }
}
```

But when I put the nonce in the header X-WP-Nonce,

```
let axiosSettings = {
        baseURL: "http://site.localhost",
        url: "/wp-json/id3/test/pc",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
            n: this.state.nonce
        },
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            "X-WP-Nonce": this.state.nonce
        }
    };
```

it tells me the

Cookie nonce is invalid and refuses to access my REST API. Why's that?

Answer (score 5):

Lots of searching later ... the action needs to be "wp_rest".

[How to get current logged in user using Wordpress Rest Api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381521/how-to-get-current-logged-in-user-using-wordpress-rest-api)