# Wordpress get user info from same browser logged into site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to use the Wordpress API wp_get_current_user(), however it's always returning the 0 user, with empty data. I am on a fresh install of Wordpress and I have just created my own theme and added an API hook.

I see lots of guides/info on grabbing data using Nonce from a separate client/computer, but I'm just trying to get the $user from the same browser that should be already logged in via the wordpress admin interface. I've verified that my browser has cookies set. My understanding of verification is that wp_get_current_user() should be able to use these cookies to verify my user and return data. [image: cookies].

Just to show I am logged into wordpress
[image: a]

This is my functions.php
located under wp-content/themes/myapi/functions/

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'api', 'test',array(
                  'methods'  => 'GET',
                  'callback' => 'logged_in_wp',               
        ));
});

function logged_in_wp($request){
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'me', 'me', array( 'status' => 200 ) );

    }

    return new WP_Error( 'not-logged in WP', 'not-logged in WP', array( 'status' => 400 ) );

}

?>
```

I'm using the following URL to access the data
`http://localhost:8080/?rest_route=/api/test`

I'm expecting it to return a me,me,200, instead, i'm only seeing the not-logged-in 400 error.

### so what is the difference between `localhost:8080` and `localhost:8080?rest_route=/api/test` that wordpress cannot figure out that I am logged in?

Comment: Have you looked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381521/how-to-get-current-logged-in-user-using-wordpress-rest-api ?

Comment: Yep, specifically mention that my cookies are already setup in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm guessing since nobody is answering and based on the readings I've done. What I'm asking for is impossible. It seems it is a security response by wordpress. You will need to authenticate even if the user is logged into Wordpress on the same domain/browser.

Answer (score 0):

What do you use to test your request?
Using postman, you can insert useful parameters which will help you on authentication. Hence if you want to logged in using the WordPress Rest api, you must insert information of the current user properly in the section Authorization (Chose basic authentication and inside, fill the username and the password of an existing account (in this case Admin) and try it again.
Here is what i did for an exemple:

[Sample image for the authorization which will soon help to know about the current user login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE5uE.png)

next using

```
$user_id = username_exists($username);
    $user =  get_user_meta($user_id);
    $response['code'] = 200;

using "get_user_meta(wp_get_current_user()->ID, 'nickname', true);"
```

you can now determine the current user been logged.

Here in this sample if you make good use of the above information, you can create a good function "`logged_in_wp()`".

[Here is my result on postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvZFk.png)

I hope this will help you by the way