# WP Rest API custom endpoint returning false on GET and POST

Tags: php, wordpress, jwt, fetch, wordpress-rest-api

I have a custom endpoint for User Meta that I've successfully registered to the WP REST API and created a custom endpoint for. However, whenever I make GET and POST requests from my single-page app (JS framework being used is Vue), the return value is 'false.'

I suspect this is happening due to some authorization issues using the JWT Authorization for WP REST API plugin.

Here are my steps taken in the functions.php app:

First I register the user meta field for the REST API:

```
//register user meta to rest api 
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'adding_user_meta_rest' );

function adding_user_meta_rest (){
    register_meta(
     'user',
     'user_likes',
     array(
         'single'       => false,
         'type'         => 'object',
         'show_in_rest' => true,
     )
 );
};
```

This step appears to be working fine since the field is showing up when I use the path "/wp-json/wp/v2/users/".

Next step, I register the custom end point:

```
add_action('rest_api_init','add_user_likes');

function add_user_likes(){
    register_rest_route(
    'v1/user_likes','/(?P<id>\d+)',[[
        'methods'=> 'GET',
        'callback'=>'get_user_likes'
    ],
    [
        'methods'=> 'POST',
        'callback'=>'post_user_likes'
    ]]);
};
```

And here are my callbacks:

```
function get_user_likes(){
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $status = $response->get_status;
    return get_user_meta($current_user_id,'user_likes');
}
```

```
function post_user_likes(WP_REST_Request $req){
    $body = $req->get_json_params();
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    return update_user_meta($current_user_id, 'user_likes',$body);
};
```

And then on the front end, here is my POST request:

```
handleLike(){
      fetch(`https://site-url.com/wp-json/v1/user_likes/${this.$store.state.userInfo.id}`,{
        method:"POST",
        body:JSON.stringify({
          post_id:this.currentPost.id,
          post_title:this.currentPost.title.rendered
        }),
         headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Authorization": `Bearer ${this.$store.state.accessToken}`
        },
      }).then(resp=>resp.json())
      .then(data=>console.log(data))
```

My GET request is also returning false.

The issue I believe is that I am not retrieving the current user ID because according to docs for get_user_meta and update_user_meta, if user id is not determined, the function will return false. Why the user id is not being determined, I don't know.
As I mentioned, I am using the JWT Authorization for WP REST API. Therefore based on my reading, I do not need to generate a nonce because WP will use the token to determine the current user. Let me know if I am wrong about that.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my issue. For future users using the JWT Authorization For WP REST API and hosting their Wordpress database on AWS Lightsail, here is how the .htaccess file must be stored on Bitnami's SSH:

```
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs”>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
</IfModule>
</Directory>
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```

Second issue I had: The token is already a string. Therefore putting it in a template literal causes parsing issues. Using a simple concatenation will do.

Here are the changes I made to authorization in the header (Note: this is using Vue's Vuex):

```
"Authorization": "Bearer" + this.$store.state.accessToken
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, set `credentials & headers` as in the example:

```
method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
      },
      body: params
    })
```

the corse can be managed by adding this to functions.php

```
function my_customize_rest_cors() {
    remove_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers' );
    add_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', function( $value ) {
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Link', false );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With' );
        return $value;
    } );
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'my_customize_rest_cors', 15 );
```

Comment: No luck. This is causing a CORS error: "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at site.com/wp-json/v1/user_likes/18. (Reason: header ‘cache-control’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response)."

Comment: I am trying to find a reason why  but now the CORS error is outputting "Reason: header ‘authorization’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response" instead of "cache-control". I assume I still need the Authorization field in the Headers object, correct?

Comment: I added " header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Cache-Control' );". My CORs error went away, but now the 'false' return has returned.

Comment: Ok I ran the postman test here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381521/how-to-get-current-logged-in-user-using-wordpress-rest-api and noticed my authentication token is just not working. I think I need to work on my config file.