# When authenticating using wordpress rest api on the same domain it comes back empty

Tags: php, wordpress, vue.js

I am authenticating using the wordpress rest api from my Vue app and using localhost it works absolutely fine, but when the app is pushed to be on the same domain as the rest api and i am logged in as an administrator it returns as not logged in? If i log out it works fine.

Any ideas?

Vue app:

```
axios.get('https://example.com/wp-json/custom/v1/login-status/', {
          headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        })
        .then(response => {
           console.log(response.data);
        }
```

Custom endpoint:

```
function custom_login_status_endpoint() {
    register_rest_route('custom/v1', '/login-status/', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'check_login_status',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true', // Allow everyone
    ));
}



function check_login_status() {
    
    
    $user_data = wp_get_current_user();
    $meta = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id());
    $is_logged_in = is_user_logged_in();

    return rest_ensure_response(array('is_logged_in' => $is_logged_in));

}
```

Comment: Are you using a JWT Plugin? Do you save the Token in a cookie or local storage? Maybe there is something wrong with the data inside of your $token variable. What about the code of your rest api endpoint, where the permission callback is "is_user_logged_in"? There are a lot of things missing. Is this all the code you are using?

Comment: @rank i am using JWT yes. I am storing it in local storage. I havent got a permission callback as it works fine locally just not when i push the app to same server. I was going to add the callback to tighten things up once id tested it. Would it cause this issue? I have additional code inside the check_login_status() function to get user meta etc that ive removed from this question but essentially im then getting user meta values and returning them in the check_login_status() response.

Comment: I retrieved the user id using this method - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42381521/how-to-get-current-logged-in-user-using-wordpress-rest-api/42469456#42469456 and is now working fine.

Comment: With "now working fine" you mean your issue is now solved? If it is, you could add your own answer, so maybe it helps others with this specific problem.